# Loop stops running java

Tags: java

For the code below, it stops running when "n" gets around 100,000. I need it to run until 1 million. I dont know where its going wrong, I am still learning Java so there might be simple mistakes in the code as well.

```
 public class Problem14{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int chainLength;
    int longestChain = 0;
    int startingNumber = 0;
    for(int n =2; n<=1000000; n++)
    {
        chainLength = getChain(n);
        if(chainLength > longestChain)
        {
            System.out.println("chainLength: "+chainLength+" start: "+n);
            longestChain = chainLength;
            startingNumber = n;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("longest:"+longestChain +" "+"start:"+startingNumber);
}
public static int getChain(int y)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(y != 1)
    {
        if((y%2) == 0)
        {
            y = y/2;
        }
        else{
            y = (3*y) + 1;
        }
        count = count + 1;
    }

    return count;   
}
}
```

Comment: I'm just curious - what is the purpose of the code, generally?

Comment: Have you tried catching an exception to see if an unhandled exception is being thrown? Maybe a stack overflow?

Comment: I am doing the Euler project, it a website where you have to solve math questions. 
Heres the question I am doing: http://projecteuler.net/problem=14

Comment: does your program crash or just stop generating output?

Comment: Are you sure it stops executing?  Nothing prints out if `chainLength > longestChain` is not true.  Perhaps you're just not finding longer chains in the period of time that you're waiting?  Try printing something (like the value of `n`) in the else case for that conditional.

Comment: Kumar Mitras solution worked, the getCHain Method goes about the int maximum, I have to use long.

Comment: Actually, this is much closer to n log_2 (n) + a possible two iterations because of the 3*y + 1. This is fine. I will delete my other comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use `long` as the `data type` **instead of** `int`

I will want this to come into light, **that the number does flung higher than** 1000000, so variable `y` needs `long` to hold it.

Comment: 1 million is well within a 32 bit integer - still trying to figure out what is wrong!

Comment: For `n`? 1,000,000 fits fine within the range of an `int`.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense here, but "1000000" barely takes 2 bytes. Why the need for a `long`?

Comment: actually he is right, the numbers do get larger than 1000000, when applying the get Chain method. I just never realized. Worked fine after the change from int to long

Comment: he is right! when invoking the `getChain` method the int gets overflown, no one here tried to run the code using longs??!

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra: Edit your post so I can change my vote. Nice job!

Comment: +1, changing the getChain() method to work with longs fixes the problem. I just tested it

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra if you had explained why, maybe people wouldnt have been so quick to give you negative points, but as I said you nailed it :).

Comment: people should try to run the code first before starting to downvote a correct answer though...

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra In the future, you should specify _what_ you're referring to.  You did not specify _which_ variable needs to be a long; as with others, I downvoted you because I thought you meant `n`.  Note that even in your edit, you've not specified which variable you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks all of you, i really got the shock of my life, seeing the negative points stocking up on the right answer... Thanks once again, to make the right , Right !!!

Comment: @Alonso +1 for asking to run the code first before reaching a decision

Answer (score 5):

It's the datatype for **y**. It should be **long**.  Otherwise it wraps round to -2 billion.

I thought I recognised this - it's Euler problem 14.  I've done this myself.

Comment: Yea thanks, Kumar beat you to it though :), so I will mark his answer correct.

Comment: You don't need the function - just put the while inside the for. Copy n into a long variable before doing the chain.  Other things you could clean up are to use operators such as y/=2 instead of y=y/2 and count++ instead of count=count+1 - etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

getChain() method is causing problem it gets to negative and then it hangs forever in the loop.